# "UnsupportedOperation: fileno" in Spacy Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, import, spacy

Anyone might know what this error is about and what to do about it?

Spacy works in python command line interface though.

I have tried to google various parts of the error, but found nothing specific.

This has been on Conda, on Windows 11, with Python 3.9.

Error message below for reference.

```
UnsupportedOperation                      Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_4264/572880994.py in <module>
----> 1 import spacy

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\__init__.py in <module>
      4 
      5 # set library-specific custom warning handling before doing anything else
----> 6 from .errors import setup_default_warnings
      7 
      8 setup_default_warnings()  # noqa: E402

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\errors.py in <module>
      1 import warnings
----> 2 from .compat import Literal
      3 
      4 
      5 class ErrorsWithCodes(type):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\compat.py in <module>
      1 """Helpers for Python and platform compatibility."""
      2 import sys
----> 3 from thinc.util import copy_array
      4 
      5 try:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\thinc\__init__.py in <module>
      3 
      4 from .about import __version__
----> 5 from .config import registry

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\thinc\config.py in <module>
     11 from pydantic.main import ModelMetaclass
     12 from pydantic.fields import ModelField
---> 13 from wasabi import table
     14 import srsly
     15 import catalogue

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wasabi\__init__.py in <module>
     10 from .about import __version__  # noqa
     11 
---> 12 msg = Printer()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wasabi\printer.py in __init__(self, pretty, no_print, colors, icons, line_max, animation, animation_ascii, hide_animation, ignore_warnings, env_prefix, timestamp)
     54         self.pretty = pretty and not env_no_pretty
     55         self.no_print = no_print
---> 56         self.show_color = supports_ansi() and not env_log_friendly
     57         self.hide_animation = hide_animation or env_log_friendly
     58         self.ignore_warnings = ignore_warnings

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wasabi\util.py in supports_ansi()
    262         if "ANSICON" in os.environ:
    263             return True
--> 264         return _windows_console_supports_ansi()
    265 
    266     return True

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wasabi\util.py in _windows_console_supports_ansi()
    234             raise ctypes.WinError()
    235 
--> 236     console = msvcrt.get_osfhandle(sys.stdout.fileno())
    237     try:
    238         # Try to enable ANSI output support

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\iostream.py in fileno(self)
    306             return self._original_stdstream_copy
    307         else:
--> 308             raise io.UnsupportedOperation("fileno")
    309 
    310     def _watch_pipe_fd(self):

UnsupportedOperation: fileno
```

Comment: It looks like I was just unlucky: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/11236

Answer (score 12):

The issue was temporarily addressed by uninstall the current version of Wasabi with an older one.

```
pip uninstall wasabi -y

pip install wasabi==0.9.1
```

The folks from Github mentioned that a newer version of Wasabi should avoid this problem.

Comment: I had the same problem on Windows 10 in a conda-forge environment, and user3081750's answer worked for me.

Comment: @Pythonic2020 How did u do that for conda?

Comment: conda install wasabi==0.9.1 -c conda-forge, and then I pinned wasabi to 0.9.1 in the conda-meta folder for that environment.  With wasabi > 0.9.1, spacy will not import at all at this time, leading to much confusion and frustration.

Comment: @GeorgeRaveen Open Anaconda Prompt and write these two commands as it is in the prompt. It will work. It worked for me.

Comment: @user3081750 What is "the current version" of `wasabi` mentioned in the answer?

Comment: Had the same issue. The above solution worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue. Maybe you can try that.

```
conda update spacy
```

It solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks!! 
Me too, dont forget kernel restart

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed with spaCy 3.4.3 and wasabi 0.10.1, at least using Python 3.9.